# Xilinx Error: Place 1018 message

Tags: xilinx

I am using a Basys2 board to program a simple string detector to read patterns like "0101". I am using the Xilinix Design Suite 13.2 for this project. The  .ucf file gives the following message.

```
ERROR:Place:1018 - A clock IOB / clock component pair have been found that are not
placed at an optimal clock IOB clock site pair. 
The clock component <reset_IBUF_BUFG> is placed at site <BUFGMUX_X1Y1>. 
The IO component <reset> is placed at site <IPAD73>.
```

Here's what my user constrains file looks like:

```
NET "x"     LOC = "P11";# input switch
NET "reset" LOC = "K3"; # reset switch
NET "ck"    LOC = "B8"; # clock
NET "b1"    LOC = "A7"; # button 1
NET "b2"    LOC = "M4"; # button 2
NET "z"     LOC = "M5"; # output
```

One of the solutions I found online was to use this in the ucf:

`CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE = FALSE;`

But unfortunately this didn't work for me. I'd appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Never ever use CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE = FALSE unless you absolutely know what you are doing (it's not really that related to your problem anyway). And even then it's risky -- don't do it. For your problem, read up on IO rules and your board's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message appears to imply that your reset is being detected as a clock signal.  That should be worrying - do you have processes which are sensitive to the *edge* of the reset signal?

You should (until you really know what you're doing) only use a couple of forms of process.

---

### Asynchronous reset

```
process (clk, reset)
begin
  if reset = '1' then
  -- async reset stuff
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
  -- sync stuff
  end if;
end process;
```

### Synchronous reset

```
process (clk)
begin
  if reset = '1' then
    --sync reset stuff
  else
    -- other sync stuff
  end if;
end process;
```

---

Also, be careful - you still need to *release* the reset signal to these processes synchronously.

Here's a good read on various reset strategies:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp272.pdf

Finally, using `CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE = FALSE;` is another no-no for almost every situation.

Comment: Sorry took me a while to accept this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got that inscrutable error message because I mistyped:

```
always @(clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    ...
```

instead of

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    ...
```

Apparently since it wasn't using the edge of `clk`, `rst` was now being treated like a clock and messing up routing.

I know this is an old question but I just hit this problem using ISE and Spartan 6; hopefully this answer will help someone (most likely me 6 months from now).